# ¿Cómo puedo escribir una línea cada tres líneas?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Estoy guardando en un fichero la salida que da el comando `tcpdump` de la siguiente forma:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf "%s\n" "$(echo $line | awk '{print $NF}' | sed 's/"//g')" >> /tmp/aux
done < <(tcpdump -lni wlan0 -vvv -s 1500 '((udp port 67) and (udp[247:4] = 0x63350103))' | grep --line-buffered -E -i 'client-id|requested-ip|hostname')
```

A destacar que cada vez que encuentra un patrón, se generan 3 líneas consecutivas y que son guardadas en un fichero.

En este caso, el resultado obtenido al fichero (/tmp/aux) es el siguiente:

```
valor1
valor2
valor3
valor1
valor2
valor3
valor1
valor2
valor3
```

Necesito procesar los datos que se generan, por lo que me gustaría saber si es posible añadir una texto al principio y final cada 3 resultados para delimitar/separar por bloques los resultados.

Es decir, que quede algo como:

```
.....
valor 1
valor 2
valor 3
.....
valor 1
valor 2
valor 3
.....
valor 1
valor 2
valor 3
......
```

Comment: No acaba de quedar claro qué pretendes. Podrías mostrar el resultado del tcpdump que inyectas en el bucle y cuál es el resultado que querrías? Veo mucho echo, sed, awk que probablemente sea redundante

Comment: he actualizado. Con tcpdump, estoy detectando quien se ha conectado a una wifi. Si se conecta 1 cliente, se generan 3 lineas. Si se conectan dos, seran 6 lineas,...

Answer (score 4):

Simplemente mantén un contador y escribe una cabecera cada tres

```
num_linea=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
do
    ! (( $num_linea % 3 )) && echo "cabecera"
    # tus cosas
    ((num_linea++))
done < <(tcpdump...)
```

Como ves, `! (( $num_lineas % 3 ))` es cierto cuando la división de `$num_lineas` entre 3 da módulo 0, es decir, cuando `$num_lineas` es múltiplo de 3.

Si necesitas poner algún valor al final del todo, simplemente añade un `echo "bla"` al final de todo.

Por cierto, no hay necesidad de redirigir cada línea, puedes indicarlo al final del `while` como sigue:

```
while ...
do
    # tus cosas
done < <(proceso) >> fichero
#                 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Ejemplo con una sucesión de números del 0 al 10:

```
$ num_linea=0
$ while read -r i;do ! (( $num_linea % 3 )) && echo "bla"; echo "$i"; ((num_linea++)); done < <(seq 10)
bla
1
2
3
bla
4
5
6
bla
7
8
9
bla
10
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes prescindir del ciclo `while` al usar `awk` o `sed`.

Por ejemplo, usaré cómo ejemplo el comando `seq 1 10` para imprimir los números en una lista del 1 al 10 y luego los filtraré con `awk` y `sed` dando lo mismo en el output.

### Usando `awk`.

```
$ seq 10 \
| awk  \
    -v cadena="..." \
    -v linea=3 \
    '1; NR % linea == 0{ print cadena }'
```

Usando `1` (o cualquier entero diferente de 0) `awk` imprime cualquier línea. Con `NR % linea == 0{ print cadena }` indico que la cadena "cadena" la imprimiré siempre y cuando el número de renglón sea múltiplo del número de línea almacenado en la variable `linea` (que en mi ejemplo es el número 3).

### Usando `sed` (funciona sólo para algunas versiones).

```
seq 10 | sed '0~3ala_cadena'
```

> **first~step**
>
> ```
> Match  every  step'th line starting with line first.  
> For example, ``sed -n 1~2p'' will print all the odd-numbered 
> lines in the input stream, and the address 2~5 will match
> every fifth line, starting with the second.  first can be zero; 
> in this case, sed operates as if it were equal to step.  
> (This is an extension.)
> ```

Puedes usar google translate para traducir lo citado.

Además que el comando `a` (después de `0~3`) indica que lo siguiente va a ser añadido después de la línea anterior.

El resultado de ambas será.

```
$ <la opcion que elijas ya sea de sed o awk>
1
2
3
...
4
5
6
...
7
8
9
...
10
```

Ambos los podrías usar a la salida del comando dentro del `while` y prescindir de crear nuevas variables además las secciones con `read` y con `printf`.

Es decir, tu código (de una línea) podría quedar de alguna de las siguientes maneras (no lo he probado).

```
$ tcpdump -lni wlan0 -vvv -s 1500 '((udp port 67) and (udp[247:4] = 0x63350103))' \
| grep --line-buffered -E -i 'client-id|requested-ip|hostname' \
| tr -d '"' \
| sed '0~3a......'
```

O así:

```
$ tcpdump -lni wlan0 -vvv -s 1500 '((udp port 67) and (udp[247:4] = 0x63350103))' \
| grep --line-buffered -E -i 'client-id|requested-ip|hostname' \
| tr -d '"' \
| awk  \
    -v cadena="......" \
    -v linea=3 \
    '1; NR % linea == 0{ print cadena }'
```

Donde prescindo de varios comandos que usaste y uso `tr -d '"'` para eliminar el caracter `"`.

Comment: De hecho `NR % linea == 0 {}` podría ponerse directamente como `! (NR % linea) {}`.